# DocuSign Review status failed

Tags: docusignapi

i have mailed to 20 clients from demo account.All 20 docs sign is completed still  i am getting integrator key Review status failed  Review Result:  Please ensure you have 20 or more consecutive error-free API transactions.  Verify that your transactions comply with API rules and limits.  What is mean by 20 or more consecutive error-free API transactions.?  What exactly have to do for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make actual Api calls to send envelopes in the Demo environment.

See more information [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#go-live-requirements)

> To promote an Integrator Key from a developer sandbox to a live production account you need at least 20 API test transactions run in the DocuSign Demo environment. DocuSign analyzes those transactions to ensure they are in compliance with [API Rules and Limits](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#api-rules) before allowing the key to be enabled in production.

Comment: @M.shailesh Please accept the answer if it resolved your question.